# WCF callback not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I made a WCF service which makes a callback to a WPF client. I just show the progress in a textbox in the WPF client. What I got first is cross thread operation not valid. Then I modified the client side code and implemented using methods such as `Invoke()` and `BeginInvoke()`. Now the client side code shows only the value 100%. Actually it should display the values from 0-100%. Any solutions?

The code at wcf service:

```
namespace ReportService
{
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant,InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class Report : IReportService
    {
        public void ProcessReport()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
              OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IReportCallback>().ReportProgress(i);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code at client:

```
namespace Report
{
    [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form,ReportService.IReportServiceCallback
    {
        delegate void delSetTxt(int percentCompleted);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InstanceContext ic= new InstanceContext(this);
            ReportService.ReportServiceClient client = new ReportService.ReportServiceClient(ic);
            client.ProcessReport();
        }
        public void ReportProgress(int percentCompleted)
        {
           // this.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.textBox1.Text = percentCompleted.ToString(); }));
            Thread t = new Thread(() => setTxt(percentCompleted));
            t.Start();

        }
        public void setTxt(int percentCompleted)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new delSetTxt(setTxt), new object[] { percentCompleted });
                return;
            }
            this.textBox1.Text = percentCompleted.ToString() + " % complete";

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered how fast is your operation? Maybe your eye see only the last 100% value because all other previous values are reported too fast. Also, to be more helpful, you should put your code: the wcf part and wpf part. Otherwise is just guessing for us.

Comment: It's on line 55 of foo.cs.

Comment: i slowed down the process.It shows only after 100%.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something,  but why start a thread?  BeginInvoke, returns immediately.

Comment: i tried without thread at first.But it was showing cross threading not valid error.Then i modified the code by adding thread from solutions given in internet.But nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the call is made to the service, the GUI thread is stuck in the button_click method.
So the GUI thread must not be frozen.
There are (at least) two solutions that work, I tested them :

1. Put `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]` both on the server and the callback operation
2. Put `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]` on the callback operation and don't lock GUI thread with `await/async`:

   ```cs
   private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {  
     InstanceContext ic = new InstanceContext(this);  
     ReportServiceClient client = new ReportServiceClient(ic);  
     await client.ProcessReportAsync();  
     //client.ProcessReport();  
   }
   ```

Good luck